# Could not find class io.confluent.connect.avro.ConnectDefault

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I am facing a similar issue as mentioned in https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/issues/22. I changed my JDBC source configuration as per the recommendation in the comment but still facing the same issue. 
Can you please help me what I am missing? Please find below my configuration and my Kafka Stream

***JDBC Source configuration***

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
timestamp.column.name=changeDateTime
incrementing.column.name=id
connection.password=xxxx
tasks.max=2
table.types=TABLE
mode=timestamp+incrementing
topic.prefix=Order-Topic
poll.interval.ms=5000
validate.non.null=true
query=select id, type, status, reservationId, processType, changeDateTime from order
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
transforms=SetSchemaName
transforms.SetSchemaName.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value
transforms.SetSchemaName.schema.name=com.raj.reservation.api.Order
transforms.SetSchemaNameschema.version=3
connection.user=testuser
connection.url=<my msql jdbc server>
```

***Kafka Stream App***

```
       Properties property = new Properties();
        property.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "Order_App_ID");
        property.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "http://localhost:9092");
        property.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        property.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        property.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
        property.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");

       StreamsConfig streamconfig = new StreamsConfig(property);

       Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
       final Serde<T> valueSpecificAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde();
       final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections
                .singletonMap(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
       valueSpecificAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false); // `false` for record values


        StreamsBuilder streamBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, T> kafkaEventStream = streamBuilder
                .stream(SRC_TOPIC, Consumed.with(stringSerde, valueSpecificAvroSerde))
                .peek((k, v) -> {
                    Order order = (Order) v;
                    LOG.info(
                        "============> ***************************************** Reservation Record {}, {}", k,
                        order.getReservationId(), order.getStatus(),
                        order.getChangeDateTime()); });

        LOG.info("Started Service {} with the following config:" + "\nInput topic    : {}" + "\nStream configs : {}",
                "KafkaStreamAppTest", SRC_TOPIC, printConfigs(property));
        KafkaStreams kafkaStream = new KafkaStreams(streamBuilder.build(), streamconfig);
        kafkaStream.start();
        kafkaStream.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
            LOG.error("Thread {} had a fatal error {}", t, e, e);
        });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(35000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LOG.info("Shutting down the Yelling APP now");
        kafkaStream.close();
```

Comment: Can you describe your own issue please. What are you doing, what code are you running, what versions, how are you running it, etc? It's useful to link to issues that you think might be related but the error message alone is not sufficient.

Comment: I am running an Kafka-connect app using docker image(landoop/fast-data-dev) and a Java App to consume event produced by connect through Kafka-Stream. I want to use my className instead of io.confluent.connect.avro.ConnectDefault so configured transforms=SetSchemaName
still getting error "Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class io.confluent.connect.avro.ConnectDefault 

The Kafka-client and Kafka-Stream versions in Java app is 2.0.1 and in Kafka-connect app is 2.0.1-L0

Comment: It's working fine. After resolving a typo error in the Kafka connect config  Also there was some incompatible message consumption of (older version message) with the new Avro Schema object. I reset the offset in Kafka-stream app to newer message compatible to newly generate Avro schema object of my type